# Data is not inserted in ibm db_2 cloud

Tags: node.js, db2, ibm-cloud

I am trying to insert data into ibm DB2 with nodeJs. My code gets executed without any error but the data is not inserted in ibm DB2 table. Can someone please help me?

This is my code

```
import ibm from "ibm_db";
import { connectionString } from "../db.js";

const signup = (req, res) => {
    const { firstName, lastName, dob, phoneNumebr, password, doctor } = req.body;
    const conn = ibm.openSync(connectionString)
    const insetQuery = `INSERT INTO USER (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, PHONENUMBER, DOB, PASSWORD, DOCTOR) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`;
    conn.querySync(insetQuery, [firstName, lastName, phoneNumebr, dob, password, doctor]);
    res.send("Data inserted successfully")
    conn.closeSync();
}
```

I get the response that data inserted successfully but data is not inserted in the ibm db2 table.

Comment: How did you check that it was not inserted? Are the table accessed by the code and from your check the same, in the same schema? Do you mean "successfully" if you receive the message sent by the code or when checking for errors? How are errors checked by your code?

Answer (score 0):

I'll do "quick" since I may not get a chance to test your code soon:

This is a snippet of how I'm currently doing an UPDATE of a db2 field (and subsequently printing it to see/confirm the change), which I believe is simple to convert to an INSERT. I'm hoping this may be useful to you as a comparison to your code, for your troubleshooting.

Edited: Here is updated code that is an entire index.js file that works (node index.js), as a better example. Every time I run it, it adds another record to the table (it's a two field table but the first column is an identity field that auto-generates a sequence number).

```
const ibmdb = require('ibm_db')
const copyFile = require('./src/utils/copyFile')

const DBAPIKEY = process.env.DBAPIKEY
const DBHOST = process.env.DBHOST
const DBNAME = process.env.DBNAME
const DBPORT = process.env.DBPORT
const DBSCHEMA = process.env.DBSCHEMA

copyFile('./lib/db2consv_ee.lic', './node_modules/ibm_db/installer/clidriver/license/')

ibmdb.open("DATABASE=" + DBNAME + ";HOSTNAME=" + DBHOST + ";APIKEY=" + DBAPIKEY + ";PORT=" + DBPORT + ";PROTOCOL=TCPIP;Authentication=GSSPLUGIN;Security=SSL;", (err,conn) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  const query10 = "insert into " + DBSCHEMA + ".lab_division (DIV_CODE) values ('99') ;"
  conn.query(query10, (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    console.log("DBSCHEMA.lab_division = " + JSON.stringify(data))
    const query102 = "select * from " + DBSCHEMA + ".lab_division ;"
    conn.query(query102, (err, data) => {
      if (err) console.log(err)
      console.log("DBSCHEMA.lab_division = " + JSON.stringify(data))
    })  
    conn.close(() => {
      console.log('Done')
    })  
  })  
})
```

Comment: Sorry 05J6- Kapil, I'm belatedly inferring you have a lot more code wrapped around this (req,res etc), I assume using express server, so my code example here isn't directly useful.